# Is there a way to make sublime 3 spell check to check words with CAPITAL LETTERS?

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to make sublime 3 spell check to check words with CAPITAL LETTERS? I'm typing here and the spell check just ignore words with 2 or more capital letters. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I found a very bad palliative solution for the problem, but it works. It is using OpenOffice writer editor. There you can go to tools, spelling and Grammar, click options, and, then, set verify capitalized, and, also, words with numbers. This can give me a hand on seeing bad typed words in my code. But it is a bad solution, c'os I'm using Sublime, so I have to open it in open office Writer just to use the spell checker. Also, I have to "feed" the dic with the right words in Writer. Hope this could give a hand to those with the same problem, but the ideal solution was to have these spell checker options inside Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

By default, no. You could potentially add a dictionary that has words in all caps and then it'll work. I looked for a couple minutes and didn't see one but you might get lucky.

Comment: I read the documentation. There's no way to make a "bad list". Too bad... But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text uses Hunspell as the spell-checking engine:

> Sublime Text uses Hunspell for its spell checking support. Additional
>   dictionaries can be obtained from the OpenOffice.org Extension List.
>
> Dictionaries in a format ready to be used by Sublime Text are available at https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries.
>   https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/spell_checking.html

Hunspell does not allow case insensitive spell-checking 
[How to check spelling in Hunspell with case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882046/how-to-check-spelling-in-hunspell-with-case-insensitive)

I am a little lost as how the suggestion by [@Giollia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10099932/giollia) is expected to work. Adding a new dictionary will supply a new list of **valid** spellings, how is that going to help highlight misspellings?

Comment: I was looking for a 'bad list' DIC or something like that, but no luck until now. Anyway, a bad list would not help so much. I like it to check it all, but the words on the white list or DIC. A case sensitive spell check would do the trick. Let's keep looking for a solution. Thank you guys for the attention.